# Move jQuery custom tooltip with mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a jQuery custom tooltip and I want it to move with mouse.
Here's my script.js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        // Tooltip only Text
        $('.masterTooltip').hover(function(){
                // Hover over code
                var title = $(this).attr('title');
                $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
                $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
                .text(title)
                .appendTo('body')
                .fadeIn('slow');
        }, function() {
                // Hover out code
                $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
                $('.tooltip').remove();
        });
});
```

Comment: Can you describe the exact issue you're having?

Comment: What's your question???

Comment: I want the tooltip to move with the mouse.

Comment: It moves now with mouse?

Comment: Don't forget to make answer useful.

Comment: You also don't forget to make question useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        // Tooltip only Text
        $('.masterTooltip').hover(function(){
                // Hover over code
                var title = $(this).attr('title');
                $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
                $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
                .text(title)
                .appendTo('body')
                .fadeIn('slow');
        }, function() {
                // Hover out code
                $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
                $('.tooltip').remove();
        }).mousemove(function(e) {
                var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
                var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
                $('.tooltip')
                .css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple trick. Just change .appendTo('body') to .appendTo($(this)) and apply position absolute to your tooltip class. I have done it by some inline css for you in the following code.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        // Tooltip only Text
        $('.masterTooltip').hover(function(){
                // Hover over code
                var title = $(this).attr('title');
                $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
                $('<p class="tooltip" style="position:absolute; padding:5px; margin:0px; background-color:#ff00ff"></p>')
                .text(title)
                .appendTo($(this))
                .fadeIn('slow');
        }, function() {
                // Hover out code
                $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
                $('.tooltip').remove();
        });
});</script>
```